# In opencart How to get my templates contact us page

Tags: opencart

I need to display my templates contact us page instead of default contact us page.How to get the link for my templates contact us page.

Under catalog->information i can't find my templates contact us page but in my template folder i am having the contact us page(contact.tpl) with in information folder.

Comment: Are you using a new theme?

Comment: Yes but i cant get the layout of my theme with side bar like i am getting for other information pages @Sankar V

Comment: Did you check whether your theme has got a template for contact? `your_new_theme_folder/template/information/contact.tpl` - check whether this file exists or not!

Comment: Yes i have verified it exist.

Answer (score 0):

In `catalog/controller/information/contact.php`, you can find the code for selecting template file as below:

```
    //condition checks whether the current theme has got a template file for contact.
    if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/information/contact.tpl')) { 
        $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/information/contact.tpl';
    } else {  // fall back to default contact template if current theme doesn't have a template file for contact
        $this->template = 'default/template/information/contact.tpl';
    }
```

If the file exists for the new theme, then check the file permission.

Have a nice day!!

Answer (score 0):

I have got the output by updating the layout for my contact us page and append the modules which i need to show it in the contact page layout(column-left).